# Test cases for SimpMessagingTemplate for rabbitmq in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-websocket, spring-rabbit, qpid

I want to write test cases for `SimpMessagingTemplate` using `rabbitmq` in `springboot`. I have already tried to write the same using `qpid-broker`having version mentioned below.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
            <artifactId>qpid-broker</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>  
         </dependency>
           <dependency> 
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
          <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId> 
           <version>1.1.5</version>
         </dependency> 


      <dependency>
          <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId> 
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId> 
             <version>1.1.5</version>
       </dependency>
```

but as I tried to execute the test cases. I am getting `IO.NETTYEXCEPTION...` or some other exceptions. It is not getting succeed either I am trying to assert with correct data. Now I want to know that is there any other way or method to write test cases for SimpMessagingTemplate using RabbitMQ. Is there any other alternative for `qpid-broker` or should I need to make some improvements in my test cases.

Comment: You need to show what is your tests Are and also be sure that you have STOMP plugin enabled on the RabbitMQ

Comment: yes i enabled stomp plugin also